# How to multiline content using xml to html

Tags: c#, .net, html, xslt, xpath

I am having a string which is multiline in content and I use br tag or "\n" or Environment.newLine for it. Which I finally assign to XMLwriter like

writer.WriteElementString("FINALDESTINATION", valFinalDest);

But after loading the xsl file and writing my html using XmlTextWriter I loose the new line in the resulting html file. Is there any way I could retain the newline in the resulting html file.

Using br tags results in inline br tags in the html, while environment.newline and "\n" does not renders the final html with multiline content but in a single line.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700435/writing-xmldocument-to-file-with-specific-newline-character-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Replace new line with `br`, `p`, `div`, etc.
2. Put content inside `pre` element, which preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Comment: Included pre tags in xsl file, works great. Thanks a lot @Kirill

Answer (score 0):

Use [**XML CDATA**](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp).

Comment: stringvalue = "<![CDATA[" + stringvalue + "]]>" in code was resulting the  html to have cdata as text included it. And if I was using it in xsl file then it was giving the xsl format as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property Indent of the object of type XmlWriterSettings to true and pass this object to the XmlWriter.Create method as second parameter.